# p:dataExporter not exporting just the displayed page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm doing project in PrimeFaces. I want export datatable data using dataexporter. My problem is using a dataexporter attribute to export the current displayed page content.
I try this below code:

```
<p:dataTable id="tbl" var="car" value="#{dataExporterView.employee}"
paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink}  
{PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {Exporters}"
paginator="true" rows="10" style="margin-bottom:20px">
 ............................
    <h:commandLink>
        <p:graphicImage name="/demo/images/xml.png" />
        <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="tbl" fileName="employee" pageOnly="true" />
    </h:commandLink>
</p:dataTable>
```

But even though I added `pageOnly="true"`, it will export all pages but I want export particular displayed page only.

Comment: What version were you using at that time?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot export particular pages of a `p:dataTable`, but you can add a pre or post processor changing the exported content similar to

```
<p:dataExporter preProcessor="#{bean.preProcessExport}"
                postProcessor="#{bean.postProcessExport}"/>
```

with

```
public void preProcessExport(Object document) {
    if (document instanceof com.lowagie.text.Document) {
        // ...
    }
}

public void postProcessExport(Object document) {
    if (document instanceof com.lowagie.text.Document) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: In current versions you can, see the docs: _"By default dataExporter works on whole dataset, if you’d like export only the data displayed on
current page, set pageOnly to true."_. Code from OP should work

Answer (score 1):

you should remove pageOnly="true" from your code then it export current page only.

Comment: That is contradictory to what the PrimeFaces docs state: _"PageOnly
By default dataExporter works on whole dataset, if you’d like export only the data displayed on
current page, set pageOnly to true."_